# unable to locate Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener when running kpm restore

Tags: asp.net-core

I copied the HelloMvc project folder to another folder "Ricky" and ran kpm restore, I got the following output:
[image]

I have no idea what's wrong. the "kpm restore" ran successfully in its original folder which is cloned from the asp.net/home repository.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally I figured out the solution. Thanks for the open source of ASP.NET vNext, I found out the source code of "[restore](https://github.com/aspnet/KRuntime/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Framework.PackageManager/Restore/RestoreCommand.cs)" command.

During the restore process, the restore command tries to find out the "root" folder of the project by this method:

```cs
public static string ResolveRootDirectory(string projectDir)
{
    var di = new DirectoryInfo(projectDir);

    while (di.Parent != null)
    {
        if (di.EnumerateFiles("*.global.json").Any() ||
            di.EnumerateFiles("*.sln").Any() ||
            di.EnumerateDirectories("packages").Any() ||
            di.EnumerateDirectories(".git").Any())
        {
            return di.FullName;
        }

        di = di.Parent;
    }

    return Path.GetDirectoryName(projectDir);
}
```

because the HelloMvc folder doesn't have those files or packages folder, so the parent folder of HelloMvc will be the root folder.

The root folder is significant because we need to copy "NuGet.config" file to the root folder. The NuGet.config indicates the package source of "AspNetVNext", so assemblies of asp.net vNext can be found.

```xml
<configuration>
    <packageSources>
        <add key="AspNetVNext" value="https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetvnext/" />
        <add key="NuGet.org" value="https://nuget.org/api/v2/" />
    </packageSources>
    <packageSourceCredentials>
        <AspNetVNext>
            <add key="Username" value="aspnetreadonly" />
            <add key="ClearTextPassword" value="4d8a2d9c-7b80-4162-9978-47e918c9658c" />
        </AspNetVNext>
    </packageSourceCredentials>
</configuration>
```

for myself, I created a packages folder in my HelloMvc folder and copied the NuGet.config to HelloMvc folder. So the HelloMvc folder itself is the root folder and NuGet.config is in position, the `kpm restore` succeeded.

Comment: Thanks - I was also stuck for sometime before reading this! Found something similar here - https://github.com/aspnet/KRuntime/issues/192

Comment: Sweet! Thanks for that resolution.  I ended up putting NuGet.config in one folder above it in my directory - c:\mk\dev\vnext.  and all apps currently in subfolders below that.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that those specific versions of the packages are no longer available on the CI server.

Open `project.json` with a text editor and replace specific versions with `*` versions.
For example:

```
"Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "0.1-alpha-build-0623",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting": "0.1-alpha-build-0519",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "0.1-alpha-build-0469"
```

becomes

```
"Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "0.1-alpha-*",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting": "0.1-alpha-*",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "0.1-alpha-*",
```

`*` version means "pick the latest version of that package".

Comment: All those versions exist on MyGet, so that shouldn't be a problem at all.

Comment: Exactly. I changed them to `0.1-alpha-*` and got the same "unable to locate" error.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be;
Add/Create the NuGet.config file within main application directory,  the content of the [NuGet.config](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/blob/master/NuGet.Config) is;

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="AspNetVNext" value="https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetmaster/api/v2" />
    <add key="NuGet.org" value="https://nuget.org/api/v2/" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

Then make sure your application  folder is one level down from the nuget.config file, the folder structure is;

[Main_Folder]
      Nuget.config
      [Application_Folder]

Then it should work!